# Possible to attach to an Amazon EBS volume from a third-party server?

Tags: amazon-ebs

I have been seeking an answer with no luck: Can I attach and mount an Amazon EBS instance on a third-party server (i.e. NOT an Amazon cloud server)?  (Assume a linux-based system)   Just wondering if this is possible, and if so, how would it be accomplished?

(Performance/security issues are beside the point at this stage of the question- the point is "can it be done" and a general overview of "how"?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no". You can only attach EBS instances to other Amazon services.

However, you could attach the EBS instance to an EC2 server, then run software of your choice on the server to share out the volume over the protocol of your choice. I cannot imagine any reason one would want to do this, however. The appropriate Amazon service for remote data storage, from a non-EC2 server, is Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Using an intermediate solution like this had occurred to me.  I am now researching Amazon S3 block based drivers such as S3QL (http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/).

Comment: For completeness, here is a list of some other S3-related drivers: http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/wiki/related_projects